# Javascript URL Parameter Capture Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am working on a django website where we have a search function in which you can choose the version, server, and user and it will display relevant results. We are now implementing a share button so you can go back to those search results. I first tested the page with variables that I set myself just to see if the table of results would load and that worked just fine. Now I am trying to use a JS function to capture the url parameters and display results based on those (the whole point).

This is the JS function I am using:

```
    function getQueryVariable(variable){
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
   }
```

I have tested the function online and it returns the correct information I want. However on the page where it should load the tables it gets stuck on loading forever. When using preset variables it works perfectly. I need to find the difference between those and what this function returns.

This is how I tested functionality:

```
   var version = "01.002.157.01.00.00.18823";
   var server = "balinor";
   var user = "jenkins";
```

When testing my function online, it returns exactly those values so I'm not sure where the difference is! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just in case you don't know, you could use `console.log()` to print variable values for debugging in javascript.

Comment: It's the simplest things that help and I don't think of when I'm stuck! Turns out they were all returning false. I changed window.location.search... to window.location.href and it works. Thank you for the helpful tip!

Comment: Fun fact: for Chrome, you can also use `.debugger;` to immediately stop JS processing and give you the value of all current variables. Super handy to drop in for quick debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with window.location.search.substring(1);
It was not returning the part of the URL that I wanted. I just used window.location.href and the parsing of the URL worked perfectly!

What helped me solve this problem was to use console.log to see that the variables are in fact not what I thought they were. Thanks to Shang Wang for that one. Solving your problems is usually simpler than you think!